# generate 'privatekey.pem' and certificate.pem on windows with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

1.how to generate privatekey.pem and certificate.pem files using  nodejs server in windows application?

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'privatekey.pem' );
var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'certificate.pem' );

https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, app).listen(port);
```

Comment: Try this answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871565/how-to-create-pem-files-for-https-web-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create .pem files for https web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871565/how-to-create-pem-files-for-https-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nodejs try this [module](https://github.com/Dexus/pem) which can generate keys and self-signed certs, you will need to install openssl as a prerequisite.  Alternatively just install openssl and use directly from command line, finally you can check out [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).