# .pem file for npm error! unable to install packages in Windows because of proxy

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting npm error `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY` upon trying to install npm package most likely because i am behind corporate proxy. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884752/npm-err-code-unable-to-get-issuer-cert-locally) which gives a possible solution to add `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` as path variable and point it to pem file. I searched for .pem file in C drive and found few inside `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\` folder, but npm gives the same error if i use them. Also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871565/how-to-create-pem-files-for-https-web-server) for generating pem using openssl but it's not working for me.

Question: Where to locate .pem file in Windows or how to generate one for above use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind proxy, you need to configure it for npm also.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_ip:port
npm config set https_proxy http://proxy_ip:port
```

to remove

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https_proxy
```