# Want to convert localhost http to https in node js .........Got some sort of error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So here is my code i dont know how to use it with this.Although its working with simpple

```
https.createserver(options)
```

but i want it to run on whole localhost project that is "app".i tried to run it by this

```
const server = https.createServer(app[options]);
server.listen(process.env.PORT, (req, res) => {
  console.log("hii")
})
```

but this error is occuring:
[Here is the error let me show the code as well][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNVph.png

```
const https = require("https");

const fs=require('fs')
const path = require("path");
var cons = require("consolidate");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const options ={
  key:fs.readFileSync('certificates/key.pem'),
  cert:fs.readFileSync('certificates/cert.pem') 
}

const server = https.createServer(app[options]);
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const signuprouter = require("./Controllers/signUpController");
const loginrouter = require("./Controllers/loginController");
const dashbaordrouter = require("./Controllers/dashboardController");
const hotelrouter=require("./Controllers/hotelsController")
const userDashboard=require("./Controllers/userDashboard")
const cors = require("cors");
const swig = require("swig");
app.use(express.json())

app.engine("html", cons.swig);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "pages/front-end"));
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
app.use("/", signuprouter);
app.use("/", loginrouter);
app.use("/", dashbaordrouter);
app.use("/", hotelrouter);
app.use("/", userDashboard);


server.listen(process.env.PORT, (req, res) => {
  console.log("hii")
})
module.exports=server;
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_ + [mcve]

Comment: eill notice it afterwards

Comment: The first argument to [`https.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/https.html#httpscreateserveroptions-requestlistener) must be an SSL/TLS configuration.

Comment: how to do it i dont know please help me with it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create .pem files for https web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871565/how-to-create-pem-files-for-https-web-server)

Comment: no i didnt found much here that solve my problem

Comment: didnt have a clue about whats wrong eith it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createServer` takes an *options object* that specifies the credentials and a *middleware function* that can be an express application.

```
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT, (req, res) => {
  console.log("hii")
})
```

Comment: Worked for me this was quiet logical as i didnt get the exact syntax